# Console.Error.WriteLine() writes to stdout

Tags: linux, mono

The following program:

```
using System;

namespace teststderr {
    class MainClass {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

when run with redirected stderr, still produces output:

```
$ ~/test-stderr/test-stderr/bin/Debug/test-stderr.exe 2>/dev/null 
Hello World!
```

According to strace, it really writes to fd 1. But if I don't redirect stderr, it writes to fd 2. I find this behavior rather suprising, and cannot find it described anywhere. Can anybody clarify why it behaves so?

```
mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-10)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Comment: Run your assembly directly w/ mono (`mono ~/test-stderr/test-stderr/bin/Debug/test-stderr.exe 2>/dev/null`)

Comment: @sushihangover it still prints the message to fd 1

Comment: Must be a broken mono version (it is older), 4.8 to 5.4 works fine for me on macos and ubuntu

Comment: Must be a broken version, 4.8 to 5.4 work fine for me in macos and ubuntu

Comment: Right, thanks. Seems to be fixed by [this](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/15cc0d6be2540e356)